# ORA-06413 -- .Net OracleClient connection not open

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio-2010

Environment:
Web Server: Windows Server 2008 R2 (64-bit)
DB (on db-server): Oracle version 8 (not supported by Oracle)
Oracle client on web server: version 8
Visual Studio 2010 Web Developer Express

Connection String:

```
<add name="Ora" connectionString="Data Source=X;Persist Security
Info=True;User ID=UID;Password=PW;Unicode=True"
providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" />
```

code:

```
OracleConnection OraCon =  new OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Ora"]);
string sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name";

OraCon.Open();
OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(sql, OraCon);
```

I am able to connect to the database using the SQL-Plus tool. I am also able to connect to the database using the Database Explorer window in Visual Studio.

However, when I run the above code, I get the ORA-06413 (connection not open) error.

I have already confirmed that Visual Studio is not installed in the Programs(x64) folder (thus eliminating the "parentheses" error.

Cannot upgrade database version (client's choice).

Any thoughts?

Comment: What's a "parentheses error"?  Specifically which line throws the error you're seeing?

Comment: The "parentheses error" is when the OracleClient throws the ORA-06413 connection-not-open error because Visual Studio is installed in the default Programs (x86) folder. Apparently, Oracle can't handle parens in the path.

Comment: And the line that throws the error is the OracleDataAdapter line.